# Questions answered by asker

Tags: discussion

I've handled a couple of questions from other posters where, after some comments/questions to the OP, they worked out the solution on their own. I've been advising them to post their solution as an answer and accept it, is that what they should be doing? Or, should the questions just be deleted?

Comment: depends. Is the question valid and on topic for Stack? If it is, then keep it and answer it yourself. Remember Stack is not just for your help, it's to help anyone who tries to solve the same issue. So if your question is clear, understandable, not a simple "oh I made a typo in my code", then by all means keep it, answer it, accept it :).  If, on the other hand, it wasn't valid or on topic for Stack... then delete it (or build a time machine and prevent yourself from asking it in the first place)

Comment: sorry, I meant questions from other people where I was commenting... but the advice is still valid, thanks. Cleaned up my wording a bit.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the edit. In the end the comment stays valid, just change the "you" for "other posters".  But yeah, all in all, Stack is meant to be a repository of knowledge. So if the question can help achieve that, it definitely shouldn't be deleted :).  If you were suggesting just that to posters, then you were doing the right thing, IMHO

Comment: That was my reasoning too.

Comment: yup, that answers my question perfectly. So now... what to do with THIS question?

Comment: @DrewJordan since you don't have the rep to vote to close (only flag) there isn't much you can do. You could flag for closure, but it won't make it happen any faster. You could delete it, but you don't have to,